# Systemd for embedded devices

Tags: boot, systemd

I want to port some upstart scripts to systemd. But I want fully control of the services that get started(and the order). I have stripped down the folder of units and wrote one from the begining. Things get started in the desired ordered but I can see some tries for some default units like:

> [0.791694] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.socket: Failed to load configurationn: No such file or 
>   [0.792422] systemd[1]: syslog.target: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
>   [0.793083] systemd[1]: var.mount: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
>   [0.793677] systemd[1]: var-run.mount: Failed to load configuration: No such

How can I get rid of this. Can anyone point me to a guide for embedded systems with systemd. Searched for ones but couldn't find the right ones.

Also I need control of cgroups and when filesystem get mounted.

Comment: This should be moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not sure that it should be moved there. It may resume to the way you compile systemd.

Comment: Last place to move it to unix list. Systemd doesn't work on unix.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are seen because the systemd unit files are available in your system and is referred to by some target unit under `Wants`
Cleaning up these dependencies shall get rid of these messages.
There is no guide specific to embedded systems. Systemd was initially started for desktop and can be used across.